# Swift virtual operator?

Tags: swift, oop

Assume we have class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    // some variables
}
```

and we have == operator for class Foo:

```
func ==(left: Foo, right: Foo) -> Bool {
    return left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y && etc.
}
```

And then we want to use it in some Generic function

```
    class func mergeUnique<T: Equatable>(workaround: T) -> ((data: [T], newData: [T]) -> [T]) {
        return { (data: [T], newData: [T]) in
            var res = data
            for newElem in newData {
                var duplicate = false
                for oldElem in res {
                    if oldElem == newElem {
                        duplicate = true
                        break
                    }
                }

                if !duplicate {
                    res.append(newElem)
                }
            }

            return res
        }
    }
```

The problem is that == operator is actually an global scope function, not class method (as we can do it in C++), so when function receives Equatable objects it uses == operator of Equatable protocol, not == operator of Foo class. I need something like virtual behavior in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try to make your class equatable: class Foo: Equatable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly define your class as `Equatable`

```
extension Foo: Equatable {}

func ==(left: Foo, right: Foo) -> Bool {
  return awesomeEquatableLogic
}
```

Comment: Great. Just needed to add `public` before operator implementation and now all works great. Not very clear behavior as for me (comparing to C++). Thanks

Comment: For what I understand, you can consider that swift have virtual methods by default. The specificity of `C++` is that it tries to always do static dispatch (done at compile time, hence the need to mark methods as `virtual`), where most of other object oriented language work with message passing at runtime.

Comment: Yes, C++ ideology is 'no overhead', so by default methods are non virtual, but methods, marked as virtual, act exactly like methods in Java or C#. Part that was unclear for me is that == function in swift is not method (I mean not member function). But de facto it demonstrates virtual behavior and works like methods.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your class conform to Equatable protocol:

```
class Foo: Equatable {
    ...
}
```

If you don't do that the program doesn't know how to check for equality and it will use the default implementation.
Once you do that it will use custom == operator.